# Forcing a large number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function which compares two numbers. If one number is bigger than the other, then a function runs.

```
if (x > y) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

I have a situation where I need `x` to always have a greater value than `y`.

At the moment I am doing this by using a very large number, like so

```
var x = 9999999999999999
```

Although this works perfectly well, it feels like a hack.

I have considered using a function to calculate a number which will always be bigger than `y`, but it seems counterproductive to add extra calculations to a program when not strictly necessary.

Can anyone confirm what is the best practice in this situation?

Comment: const x = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER?

Comment: `Number.MAX_VALUE` ?

Comment: Do you need `x` to be greater than `y`, or do you just need the `// do something` block to run irrespective of the values of `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maxValue = x > y ? x++ : y++;

This will be useful if you need it to always generate a value greater than those entering the condition.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the maximum of [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

```js
console.log(Infinity);

console.log(Infinity > Number.MAX_VALUE); // always true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE)

```
x = Number.MAX_VALUE
```

witch equals to 1.7976931348623157e+308

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity).

> The value Infinity (positive infinity) is greater than any other number.

```
var x = Infinity; 
// or Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
// or 1/0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x > y) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

> I have a situation where I need x to always have a greater value than
> y.

Are you trying to force the `true` condition in order to call `// do something` directly or is there a need beyond this code for `x` to have a larger value?

Instead of forcing the `true` condition, move the somethings into functions, then update your code

```
(x > y) ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
```

Now you can call `doSomething()` whenever you want.